# Is it possible to add different table header in a Colspan

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, html-table

I am trying to add text above every column in `Colspan` but nothing works as expected.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxQPj.png as shown here in the image I want in columns of `colspan` to be
1 2 3 4 5 O, but I don't know how to make that.
Here is example of my code

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="30%">
            @DbResHtml.T("Натпреварувач", "Resources")
        </th>
        <th  width="1%">
            @DbResHtml.T("Бр.", "Resources")
        </th>
        <th width="1%">@DbResHtml.T("ВИ", "Resources")</th>
        <th width="1%">
            @DbResHtml.T("П.", "Resources")
        </th>
       <th colspan="6" scope="colgroup">
            @DbResHtml.T("Грешки", "Resources")<br>
            @DbResHtml.T("12345O", "Resources")
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

`Tbody` code is not included for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm following your question correctly, but if you want text above each column a colspan will prevent that from working correctly. You would need to split them into their own  elements.

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th width="30%">
        @DbResHtml.T("Натпреварувач", "Resources")
    </th>
    <th  width="1%">
        @DbResHtml.T("Бр.", "Resources")
    </th>
    <th width="1%">@DbResHtml.T("ВИ", "Resources")</th>
    <th width="1%">
        @DbResHtml.T("П.", "Resources")
    </th>
    <th>@DbResHtml.T("Г", "Resources") <br>
        @DbResHtml.T("1", "Resources")
    </th>
    <th>@DbResHtml.T("р", "Resources")<br>
        @DbResHtml.T("2", "Resources")</th>
    <th>@DbResHtml.T("е", "Resources")<br>
        @DbResHtml.T("3", "Resources")</th>
    <th>@DbResHtml.T("ш", "Resources")<br>
        @DbResHtml.T("4", "Resources")</th>
    <th>@DbResHtml.T("к", "Resources")<br>
        @DbResHtml.T("5", "Resources")</th>
    <th>@DbResHtml.T("и", "Resources")<br>
        @DbResHtml.T("O", "Resources")</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

As it appears you are pulling from a Db so you could split the strings into arrays and perform a loop to generate each  for each character in the array.

Hope this helps.